# If a civilisation is built on the back of a moving body, what is a day like?

Tags: society, environment, time

What this question is asking is that if there were a group of people living on the back of a something that itself moves, how is the passage of time measured for days, weeks and seasons as these things may change as the thing moves. What would their calendars and days be like?
This would be as if spending your entire life on boat, except this is the way the whole civilisation has lived.
This being lives on Earth

Comment: Does this "thing" moves in a world that has nights, days and seasons?

Comment: Does the Earth move? Are we talking about a giant turtle? Maybe with some elephants? I think we need to know how this moving thing works, what its scale is, and what it is moving through.

Answer (score 3):

On the risk that this question will be forced to edits that render my answer moot …

Based on what little information you give, it sounds like your people will interpret the movements of the enormous Hilloþ the same as would any migratory or seafaring people — except that they have little control over where it goes.
There's also that 200-ft cliff off the side of the Hilloþ and to a different way of life.

I mean, sure:  from time to time, some brash and reckless persons have gone and prodded through the sod covering the back of the Hilloþ, and this has resulted in tumultuous quakes and calamity for everyone else.  Almost nobody does so for the purpose of goading the Hilloþ to move about, though.  The Hilloþ is an immense beast, and it doesn't change direction rapidly.
Usually they do so while digging for the purposes of agriculture or war.  There are ancient decrees, written on the obelisks that protrude from the Hilloþ, but every now and again — you know how it goes.

The great Hilloþ is a temperate creature.  It travels between the north and south hemispheres during the course of a year.  It also seems to drift slowly to the east, but it takes a century or more for it to complete a circuit around the equatorial girdle of the planet Plácè.

Fortunately, the length of day and night are varied by almost negligible quantities due to the sheer mass of the Hilloþ.  It doesn't tend to wander much, in any direction, during a daily period.

All in all, it isn't much different from being a seagoing Gypsy or Berber.

Comment: How do they record, measure and expect time

Comment: That is the question